# There is few rules and regulations.
Is it a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

There is few rules and regulations.
Is it a grammatically correct sentence? I mean whether it be *IS* or *ARE*

Comment: "_There are a few rules and regulations._"

Answer (score 1):

As @Varun Nair says in the comment, it should be

> There *are a* few rules and regulations.

“A few rules and regulations” is plural, so you have to use “are”.

You should also say *a few* rather than *few* in this context, probably. “A few” means “a number of” or “some.” “Few” by itself means “not many.” I assume the former is what you mean, unless your goal is to point out how small the number of rules and regulations is.

Comment: In my text book(Strategic management creating competitive advantages by dess and others), a sentance about the advantages of simple structure was ''Decision making is highly centralized, there is little specialization of tasks, *few rules and regulations*, and an informal evaluation and reward systems". Is it correct sentance , although the *few rules and regulations* follow the verb *IS*?

Comment: Thanks for the context. In this case “few” rather than “a few” is correct because the point is that there are not many rules and regulations. But the grammar is sloppy- you would not say “there *is* few rules and regulations.” “Few rules and regulations” is a plural noun phrase. The authors list the advantages but since the forms of them are not parallel it doesn’t quite work. To be correct it should be “Decision making is highly centralized, there is little specialization..., there *are* few..., and *there are* informal evaluation and reward systems.”